# Send info with ajax to submit.php

Tags: php, ajax, forms, email, return

Heys guys, I've been playing around with this ajax call for a few days now. I had it posting an email with no variables earlier, but now I can't get the call to submit the form with a variable or without. Here is my code:

```
      <form id="contactform" method="post" action="submit.php">

          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="username" id="username" />

          <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" />

          <input type="button" id="submit" class="submit" value="submit"></a>

      </form>
```

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#submit").click(function(event){
   var data = $('#contactform').serialize();
   event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
         url: "submit.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: data,
         success: function() {                        
             alert("Success!");        
         }
       }); 
     return false; 
   });
 });
</script>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
    $from = "info@email.com";
    $usersubject = "Thank You!";
    $usermessage = "Thank you for signing up!";
    $to = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $subject = "Form Info";
?>

<?php
    $name = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
    $message = "Name: $name
    Email: $email";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($email,$usersubject,$usermessage,$headers);
    echo 'Success';
?>
```

submit.php works when you access it directly with the variable (www.website.com/submit.php?username=Dave&email=davesemail@mail.com). Is there an error somewhere here that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This one extra `});`, is it because you missed to include `document.ready` in this question or is this how it is in your implementation?

Answer (score 0):

This what you want but you should learn about Json. 
data={
"name":"James Bond","email":"AGENT007@MI5.gov "
}

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a document ready block:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // your code here
});
```

Then make sure you put your javascript code just before the closing body tag ().
Otherwise if you put the javascript in the header without a document ready the javascript code will be executed before the submit button is present on the page and therefor the $('#submit') selector will return zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
     <form  method="post" action="submit.php">

     <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="username" id="username" />

     <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" id="email" />

     <input type="button" onClick="submit()" value="submit"></a>

     </form>
```

AJAX:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function submit(){
  var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
     $.ajax({
     url: "submit.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {uname:user,email:email},
     success: function() {                        
         alert("Success!");        
     }
      }); 
     return false; 
   }
   </script>
```

PHP:

```
     <?php
    $from = "info@email.com";
    $usersubject = "Thank You!";
    $usermessage = "Thank you for signing up!";
    $to = $_POST['email'];//one that assigned to data in ajax
    $subject = "Form Info";
      ?>

    <?php
     $name = $_POST['uname']; //one that assigned to data in ajax
     $email = $_POST['email'];//one that assigned to data in ajax
     $message = "Name: $name
     Email: $email";
     $headers = "From:" . $from;
    //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail($email,$usersubject,$usermessage,$headers);
     echo 'Success';
     ?>
```